# TreeView Control isn't still available with MSCOMCTL.OCX registered

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview, ms-access-2010, windows-7-x64

At this moment I'm working on a MS Access database, and I have difficulties with the library `MSCOMCTL.OCX`.

The problem is the following: given `Windows 7 x64`, `Microsoft Office 2010 x64` and `MSCOMCTL.OCX v6.1.98.34` (which was registered with the help of `regsvr32` in the folder `SysWOW64`), I can't use the TreeView (`MsComCtlLib.TreeCtrl.2` class) present in some forms of the database. Every time the code approaches any TreeView's (read, Node's) property, I receive the following message:

> "*Object doesn't support this property or method*" (Error 438)

while in `Windows 7 x32` the database works fine.

Trying to understand what's wrong, I discovered that the library `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)` exists in the list seen in the 'References...' dialog and is checked, but I don't see `Microsoft TreeView Control 6.0` in the list of available ActiveX Objects when I'm in the Constructor mode.

Following some solutions found in the Internet, I executed *regedit.exe* and saw that there are two "folders" in the path `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}`, `"2.0"` and `"2.1"`. Besides, the path to the file `MSCOMCTL.OCX` is in `"2.1"`, while `"2.0"` is not also empty - it contains `PrimaryInteropAssemblyName` property for example, which isn't present in `"2.1"`.

So, what should I do to make TreeViews in my database work? As I've mentioned before, I saw some solutions, but I'm afraid to use them because the computer, where the database is in, is not mine and it's undesirable to make the changes, which can affect security of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of MSCOMCTL that is installed by default is not 64-bit compatible. You're unfortunately out of luck. No amount of modifying the registry is going to make a 32-bit only control work in 64-bit office.

However, MS apparently includes a 64-bit compatible version of MSCOMCTL with Office 365 ProPlus installations ([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a717dd02-f0c1-4439-9ea5-7594643f74c8/obtaining-mscomctlocx-for-windows-10-64-bit)). You can consider buying that, or obtaining it through other means.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the setup of 32-bit MS Access has helped the application to work correctly again.